# kqueue tracking file changes - chance of losing events while processing previous ones?

Tags: python, python-2.7, freebsd, kqueue

**What I'm doing**

I'm implementing a python/kqueue-based (FreeBSD) solution to follow changes to a particular logfile, which when the KQ_NOTE_WRITE fflag is met, the change to the file is picked up and processed by another function within my python script.

**Why I'm doing it**

Ultimately, I'm taking the latest logfile entry and sending it off somewhere else as part of a quick'n'dirty accounting system.

**What I think I need to know**

1) As the logfile can see periods of high traffic, I wondered whether there would be any "atomicity", i.e while passing off the latest entry to the logfile, would we "miss" a new entry coming in?  The fact that kqueue is a "queue", I assumed not, but history has taught me that I usually end up feeling like a plonker for such assumptions.

2) Is kqueue guaranteed to fire for each event, or could multiple events slip through?  The case I'm imagining is the logfile producing 2 separate entries almost simultaneously.

Any wisdom/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct. :-)

A kqueue "event" is "expanded" if it is not in the process of being consumed when a second identical event occurs.  That is, suppose the sequence of events at the low level is something like this:

```
1: you start monitoring the log file for writes
2: something writes to the log file (this adds a "write" notice to the kqueue)
3: your process is notified, but does not have a chance to go look yet
4: something (same something as step 2, or different, does not matter)
   writes more to the log file (this merely "expands" the existing notice,
   with no effect in this case)
5: your process finally gets a chance to read the "file was written" notice
   from the kqueue
```

When step 5 occurs, the "file was written" notice will just be the one notice.  It is up to your code to figure out how much got written.  For instance, you can use `fstat()` to check the length of the file at step 1, and then another `fstat()` after step 5.  If the file is only ever appended-to, the size difference between these points is the "new data" you care about.

Note that if you see (say) 100 bytes at step 1 and 500 after step 5—say, in a step 7:

```
7: you fstat the file
```

and later get another "file was written" notice, it's possible that there was actually a "step 6" where another write happened to the file.  So you should be prepared for an even later step to find that 0 bytes were added, even though you got a notice that bytes were added, because you may have already read them after the note was appended to the kqueue.

If you're watching `syslog` type logs, note that they get "turned over" with the file being renamed (and then sometimes compressed etc) and a new file created, e.g., "messages" becomes "messages.0.bz2" and a new "messages" is created.  You can watch the directory, along with the file, and check for new file creations, to catch such cases.

Comment: Hi torek, thanks for the awesome detail! This is exactly the info I was looking for.  Thank you also for the extra advice about renaming - it is indeed a syslog-style logfile, and I already have kqueue firing on renames, so I'm not too worried there.  Your suggested algorithm of the fstat() delta is great advice.  Cheers, sc.

Comment: Same thing applies for inotify on linux.